# How can I submit form content to a Rails app from an outside static html page?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an html form on an outside legacy[coldfusion] system that i would like to submit to the create method in my users controller in my new rails app- unfortunately i'm a rails noob and clueless.

the html in the outside legacy app is:

```
<form action="http://floating-caverns-7335.herokuapp.com/users" method= "post">
<input type="text" name="name" value="nametestvalue">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="testROR">
```

the code in the rails app is the [standard noob scaffolded] method for create in the users controller:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

when i execute the first html code a new user record is created by the rails app but the value of the name field is blank.  what am i overlooking that will correctly load the name field value as specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that a new user is being created with params[:user]. So, you need to send an user hash like that `:user => { name: "an user"}` to the server, and you do that changing the input name attribute:

`<input type="text" name="user[name]" value="nametestvalue">`

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this line,

```
<input type="text" name="user[name]" value="nametestvalue">
```

This is because in following statement

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
```

you are passing params[:user] which is currently blank. This need to contain user attributes. I will suggest you to inspect web logs to check parameter list. You can do the same in firebug net panel as well.

Hope this helps!